# Tool to track web traffic of various third-party websites over time

Tags: web-apps, search-engine

I'm looking for a tool that will show me the amount of traffic a given website receives over time (i.e. not my own website, but any website I search for). This tool must also have information on organic traffic over time and referral traffic from social media websites over time, the more granularity the better -- month to month minimum, ideally day to day or week to week.

Some tools I've looked at that seem to do some of what I want include ahrefs (https://ahrefs.com/), SEMrush (https://www.semrush.com/dashboard/), and SimilarWeb (https://www.similarweb.com/). However these are all very expensive, and I don't want to pay for something if I'm not sure it meets the three requirements I outlined above. Does anyone have personal experience with any of these or some other tool that does the things I want? To summarize, said tool

1. must show total traffic, traffic from search engines, and traffic from social media sites for (almost) any website I give it
2. must show this information over time (at least month-to-month)
3. would be nice if it showed the information week-to-week or day-to-day

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for "done for you" list then try [rankedy seo](https://rankedy.com) or if you want the data on demand [mangools.com](http://mangools.com)  is good. Both of these wont cost you anywhere near ahrefs or semrush, but both are super useful when it comes to competitor research.

Comment: Mongools seems decent, but it doesn't provide traffic data for specific web pages within a website. I know I didn't ask for your recommendations to provide that, but are you aware of any tools that provide traffic information on the level of specific web pages within a website? Thanks